# TypeError 'buffer size mismatch' error when defining a series in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am trying to programmatically create a chart in an xlsx file using xlsxwriter and pandas data.
Writing cells is succeeding fine, however when I try to define a Data Series for a Scatter chart I get a TypeError 'buffer size mismatch' and I'm fairly certain my defined range is acceptable.

Example code:

```
headers = DataFrame([[-0.398,2],[-0.201,2],[-0.001,20]],columns=['Bias','Sensitivity'])
dfs = [DataFrame([[3998.28253,2.056],[3997.31816,1.978],[3996.35379,1.932],[3995.38942,1.746],[3994.42504,1.478]]),
       DataFrame([[3998.28253,2.056],[3997.31816,1.978],[3996.35379,1.932],[3995.38942,1.746],[3994.42504,1.478]]),
       DataFrame([[3998.28253,2.056],[3997.31816,1.978],[3996.35379,1.932],[3995.38942,1.746],[3994.42504,1.478]])]
       # Repeated DataFrames here for convenience

outxls = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(toplevelname),p+'.xlsx')

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(outxls)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Bias')
worksheet.write(1, 0, 'Sensitivity')

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
for i, h in enumerate(headers.index):
    worksheet.write_number(0, 2*i+2, headers['Bias'][h], )
    worksheet.write_number(1, 2*i+2, headers['Sensitivity'][h])
    for r, row in dfs[h].iterrows():
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            worksheet.write_number(r+2, 2*i+c+1, row[c])

    l = len(dfs[h])
    chart.add_series({
            'name': headers['Bias'][h],
            'categories': ['Sheet1', 3, 1, l, 1],
            'values': ['Sheet1', 3, 2, l, 2],
        })
worksheet.insert_chart('B3', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Full Error Message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-56283fee8773> in <module>()
     52                 'name': headers['Bias'][h],
     53                 'categories': ['Sheet1', 3, 1, l, 1],
---> 54                 'values': ['Sheet1', 3, 2, l, 2],
     55             })
     56     worksheet.insert_chart('B3', chart)

/Users/megablanc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/xlsxwriter/chart.pyc in add_series(self, options)
    134         # Switch name and name_formula parameters if required.
    135         name, name_formula = self._process_names(options.get('name'),
--> 136                                                  options.get('name_formula'))
    137 
    138         # Get an id for the data equivalent to the range formula.

/Users/megablanc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/xlsxwriter/chart.pyc in _process_names(self, name, name_formula)
    788                 name_formula = quote_sheetname(name[0]) + '!' + cell
    789                 name = ''
--> 790             elif re.match(r'^=?[^!]+!\$?[A-Z]+\$?[0-9]+', name):
    791                 # Name looks like a formula, use it to set name_formula.
    792                 name_formula = name

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.pyc in match(pattern, string, flags)
    135     """Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    136     a match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 137     return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
    138 
    139 def search(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: buffer size mismatch
```

Comment: You will probably need to post a small but complete example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: And/or what is the value and type of `headers['Bias'][h]` when it throws an exception. And guessing ahead, you could try wrap that in `str()`.

Comment: Edited with better example code. `headers['Bias'][h]` is `<type 'numpy.float64'>`. `headers['Sensitivity'][h]` is `<type 'numpy.int64'>`, and `row[c]` is `<type 'numpy.float64'>`.

Comment: Hi @jmcnamara, it seems you were absolutely right, problem was fixed by casting values for `name`. I never thought to look there, from what I could tell on the error message the problem was with the `'values'` step. How come the arrow isn't pointing to line 52 or 53?

Comment: *How come the arrow isn't pointing to line 52 or 53?* That is confusing. The arrow is pointing to the end of the function call but it is the first parameter, two lines earlier, that is causing the issue. I'll add an answer in case this catches anyone else and I may add a check to the module as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `name` value `headers['Bias'][h]`isn't a string and raises a TypeError when passed to the function.

The error is a little more confusing than it should be due to the fact that the data type is a `numpy.float64` which raises an unusual `buffer size mismatch` error.

The fact that the function parameters are spread over several lines also makes it look like the issue is with the `values` parameter rather than the `name` parameter.